# Creating a histogram with three variables per 'bin' in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram where each of my row names is a 'bin' and the three values (mean, median, and stdev) are plotted separately in each bin.  I've created a matrix out of my data that looks like this:

```
                 Mean  Median     Stdev
1           0.3587489 0.33040 0.2495823
0.5         0.2190726 0.12610 0.2356564
0.333333    0.2156363 0.11210 0.2373799
0.25        0.2213469 0.13030 0.2352794
0.2         0.2158040 0.11590 0.2347598
0.166667    0.2373793 0.15280 0.2389180
```

I've tried playing around with histogram and googling this, but since I'm not a statistician I'm probably not even expressing myself correctly.  If anyone could lend me a hand in this rather mundane task (or in plotting this data in a way which you think is better than a histogram), however, I'd be appreciative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with `barplot(t(mat), beside=TRUE)`